# C++ to C call: argument of type 'void (MyClass::)(u_char*,)' does not match 'void (*)(u_char*)'

Tags: c++

my rusty C++ skills got a fail after:

```
#include <pcap.h>
...
void Sniff::pcap_listen() {
 pcap_t *loc;
 char *dev;
 dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
 loc = pcap_open_live(dev,BUFSIZ,0,-1,errbuf);
 pcap_loop(loc,-1,pcap_callback,NULL);
}
```

> error: argument of type ‘void
>   (Sniff::)(u_char*, const pcap_pkthdr*,
>   const u_char*)’ does not match ‘void
>   (*)(u_char*, const pcap_pkthdr*, const
>   u_char*)’

Adding/removing 'static' definition in .h: no effect.

++ another problem:

```
listener = g_thread_create(pcap_listen, NULL, FALSE, NULL);
```

Lot of variations of ::, &, this .. was tested, most informative message was:

> src/main.cpp:281: error: argument of
>   type ‘void* (Sniff::)(void*)’ does not
>   match ‘void* (*)(void**)’

Comment: Adding `static` to the `pcap_listen` and `pcap_callback` functions should solve that.

Comment: @Victor - I'd call that rather irresponsible advice.  We have no way of knowing if such a solution is compatible with the poster's needs.  All we know is that it will get rid of THAT error.

Comment: Strictly it's more than just static, it has to be "C" linkage too because there can potentially, quite legally be differences between calling conventions for C and C++.

Comment: @Noah - it's not advice, it's a fact: he says adding `static` does not solve the compiler error, and I said that it should (though it might, of course, cause different compiler errors). It was more of a hint that more details were required, than an actual answer (which is the reason why it's a comment instead of an answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't [pass a pointer to a member function to something that's expecting a function pointer](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html#faq-33.2). Fundamentally a pointer to a member function is a completely different type than a function pointer. There is no trivial conversion between the two and can never be one as there's no `this` pointer, which is required to call a non-static member function.

Simply adding `static` doesn't technically solve the problem either, since it won't have C linkage, which *could* be a problem with a conforming implementation. In most implementations this is well behaved, but it is not portable in general and the portable solution requires using

```
extern "C" {
   void my_callback() {
   }
}
```

**Update:**

Given that both of the functions you're trying to call seem to take a `void*` "user argument" you can use this with a variable to pass a pointer to an instance of your class, e.g. something along these lines:

```
class CallbackHandler {
public:
   void my_callback();   
};

extern "C" {
   void callback_wrapper(void *arg) {
      static_cast<CallbackHandler*>(arg)->my_callback();
   }
}

void start_pcap_listen(CallbackHandler* receiver) {
   pcap_t *loc;
   char *dev;
   dev = pcap_lookupdev(errbuf);
   loc = pcap_open_live(dev,BUFSIZ,0,-1,errbuf);
   pcap_loop(loc,-1,callback_wrapper,receiver);   
}
```

It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: It's more than just the lack of a this pointer.  They're entirely different types.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that but I was trying to explain in simple terms why they have to be different types. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Of course if the API used boost::function you can bind a member function to that without having to write loads of wrappers. Having said that, when I tried debugging code that used boost::function it was extremely hard to trace through to where it called the function as it went through several layers of mpl.

Answer (score 1):

Member function and "free" function pointers are not interchangeable in C++.  Your `pcap_callback` function appears to be an instance (non-static) member of `class Sniff`.  If it is a static member, then you have to qualify it with the class name.

```
pcap_loop(loc,-1,Sniff::pcap_callback,NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you should be gleaming from these compiler messages is that pointer to members are not the same as function pointers.

Whether making your member function static and thus converting its address from 'pointer to member' to 'pointer to function' will actually fix your problem is entirely dependent upon what your needs are.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a pointer to member function while the API expects a global function pointer. You've written that adding a `static` definition in the header has no effect, it should solve the problem  since a static function isn't a member function (it's global). Could you share the reason it doesn't work when the function is static?

Answer (score 1):

Commonly this can be done by using a ThreadFunction class. We will give it a non-virtual method "invoke" and a virtual method "run". Some variation of this will work:

```
class ThreadFunction
{
public:
   virtual ~ThreadFunction();
   void invoke( bool joinable );

protected: // or private
   virtual void* run() = 0;
   friend void * my_thread_func( void * );

   GThread * gthread;   
   GError * error;
};
```

// In your cpp

```
void* my_thread_func( void * tf )
{
   ThreadFunction * func = static_cast< ThreadFunction * >(tf);
   return tf->run();
}

void ThreadFunction::invoke( bool joinable )
{
   gthread = g_thread_create( my_thread_func, this, joinable, &error );
}
```

This is just an outline of the approach. You would create your thread to derive from ThreadFunction. (joinable may well be a feature of your implementation rather than a parameter passed in).